# Add special characters in Flutter text How to show special characters in Text in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, unicode

How can we add a unicode arrow in Flutter `new Text('Arrow should come here')`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have:

```
Text("→"),
```

or

```
Text("\u{2192}"),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Runes` class which does not need any plugin

**Example**

You want to show right arrow and you know its `unicode` value ie `U+1F802`

Now to show it in text you can use `Runes` class and convert it to show arrow

Just need to use the `unicode` value after `U+` ie `1F802` and then append it with `\u`

**Usage**

```
Text(new String.fromCharCodes(new Runes('\u1F802'))),
```

[List of special charaters](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0024)